# Connecting to mysql database with mvc4 razor c# [Error]

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, razor

hi guyz i've go this error code: **An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.** in searching my text to the database..

```
        private bool IsValidRegisterNewAcct(string acctname, string dispname, string email, string password)
    {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
        bool IsValid = false;
        IsValidErrorMessage = "";
        IsValidErrorMessageInt = 0;
        string Newacctname = crypto.Compute(acctname.ToString());
        //try
        //{
            using (var db = new MainDbContext())
            {

                //db.Connection.Open();
                var user = db.user.FirstOrDefault(u => u.AcctNameSalt  == Newacctname);
                //var user = db.osoa_user.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    IsValid = false;
                    //db.Connection.Close();
                    IsValidErrorMessage = "Account Name already Exist!";
                }
                else
                {
                    var InsertNewAcctName = db.osoa_user.CreateObject();

                    InsertNewAcctName.UserId = Convert.ToString( Guid.NewGuid());
                    InsertNewAcctName.AcctName = acctname;
                    InsertNewAcctName.AcctNameSalt = crypto.Compute(acctname);
                    InsertNewAcctName.DisplayName = dispname;
                    InsertNewAcctName.Email = email;
                    InsertNewAcctName.EmailSalt = crypto.Compute(email);
                    InsertNewAcctName.Password = crypto.Compute(password);
                    InsertNewAcctName.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
                    InsertNewAcctName.UserLevel = 2;

                    db.user.AddObject(InsertNewAcctName);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //db.Connection.Close();
                    IsValid = true;
                }
            }
        /*
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IsValidErrorMessageInt = 1;
            IsValidErrorMessage = e.Message + ". Pls. contact your Administrator.";
            IsValid = false;
        }
        */
        return IsValid;

    }
```

and the error was pointing to this code:

```
var user = db.user.FirstOrDefault(u => u.AcctNameSalt  == Newacctname);
```

**UPDATE** About the Inner exception. i dont know if give you the correct one.. i tried to use this code:

```
            try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IsValidErrorMessageInt = 1;
            IsValidErrorMessage = e.InnerException + ". Pls. contact your Administrator.";
            IsValid = false;
        }
```

**MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'Extent1.DateCreated' in 'field list' at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)**

Comment: Have you looked to the inner exception?

Comment: and the inner exception says....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your inner exception it appears as though your `MainDbContext` has became out of sync with your database (looks like `Extent1` has a column which doesn't exist in the DB).

Try removing that property from the model and trying again.

Comment: ah it works!!!! gosh! thanks to Kai and rene also..... wuhuuuuu... so meaning to say i have to check my database or my table always if it is sync to my MainDBContext? this ASP.net MVC 4 is tricky and hard than php.. coz in php it doesnt matter if you will call only few fields... but now i start to love this ASP.net mvc4 razor.. thanks a lot sir james :) God bless :)

Comment: another thing is it really adivsable to put db.connection.open() and close? thanks

Comment: What's probably happened is you have had a column in the DB, generated your context and then removed that column from the DB - that results in the context being out of sync. It's fine if you *add* columns to your DB and your context is out of sync because it just means that column can't be updated. However, it's different for removing as the context will query for all properties which are part of it's model so they **have** to be in the DB.

Comment: @user2328935 under normal circumstances no you don't need to explicitly open the DB, the context takes care of all that for you. Just make sure you have it wrapped in a `using` clause so it get's disposed when you are done.